# ExtJS 4 menu position

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

I'm new to ExtJS.

I've looked in documentation and tried few possible solutions, but nothing works. I need to change the default behaviour of menus.

I have a button that triggers a menu `dropdown` and it works all fine until the browser window is too small to show entire `dropdown`, in which case it `undocks` and ExtJS is trying to fit it in the window.

I need it to stay where it is, relative to the button that triggered it.

How can I do this in ExtJS?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure how you are showing the menu, but you can try to **use the position parameter** on **Ext.menu.MenuView.**[**showBy**](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.menu.Menu-method-showBy) method in order to force it to stay in the same place always.

```
menu.showBy(button, 'tl-bl')
```

You can see a working example on how to use it [here](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/rvi)

I know that has passed about a week since you made the question, but I hope it helps to solve your problem if you are still facing it.

Comment: Setting the menuAlignment property on the button to 'tl-bl' would be cleaner than all of these. The default for menu buttons is 'tl-bl?' and it's that '?' that tells the framework to attempt to reposition the menu when it would otherwise spill off the screen.